# SAS EG DATE/TIME IN WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sas

I need to use a *date/timestamp* field in my *where* clause where it is >today()1pm

I'm setting it up to be a scheduled task, so the "today()" part is important
I dont know how to combine that with the time piece though
all I could come up with was this- and it seems like very inefficent code if it even works

```
datepart(fielda)=today() and timepart(fielda)>01:00:00pm
```

I need to be able to say here are the items with a timestamp of "today" after "1pm"

*I am passing my sql to an underlying database.

Comment: So apparently certain sas functions won't work for me because I am connecting to an Oracle database. I applied the below and it did the trick. thanks to all that replied. I learned quite a bit with this.     datefield<sysdate
to_char(datefield,'hh24:mi:ssam')<'12:39:01pm'

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PROC SQL directly (not pass-through) you can use the SAS `dhms` function:

```
proc sql noprint;
  * Assume myData contains a var named datestamp;
  create table selected as
    select * from myData
    where datestamp > dhms(today(), 13, 0, 0)
  ;
quit;
```

The function constructs a datetime value from the supplied Date, Hour, Minutes and Seconds values, hence `dhms`.

This won't work if your SQL is being passed through to the underlying database because it's unlikely to understand the `dhms` function.

Comment: I am passing the sql through to another database and it looks like the it is not recognizing the dhms function. sorry i did not think that would have mattered. i will update my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

this is so much fancier and is easier to use

```
datefield between to_date(to_char(sysdate-1,'mm/dd/yyyy') || '12:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date(to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy') || '08:32:27','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

this will supply all values from yesterday at 12pm through 832am today

Answer (score 0):

Combine a date9-formatted macro variable with the time. This will create a datetime literal. This method is going to be as efficient as can be, since SAS resolves the literal one time only, and can then use any existing index on `datestamp`.

```
%let today = %sysfunc(today(), date9.);

proc sql noprint;
    create table selected as
        select *
        from mydata
        where datestamp > "&TODAY.:13:00:00"dt
    ;
quit;
```

You can confirm the value with the code below.

`%put %sysfunc(putn("&TODAY.:13:00:00"dt, mdyampm24.) );`

Comment: While a scheduled task probably would have a reliable `&SYSDATE9`, don't forget the caveat that `&SYSDATE9` is set at startup and does not necessarily return current date.

Comment: Joe, would you mind elaborating on this a little further please. Both this and the dhms function looked like usable solutions. What do you mean that the sysdate is set at startup, isn't sysdate the way to dynamically use whatever the current date is?

Comment: Sysdate is the value of when your SAS session begins. For example, try leaving SAS open on your computer overnight and come back the next day. If you do %put &sysdate9, you'll see that it's the value of yesterday.

You can get around this by creating a new macro variable. I updated the code to reflect it.

%let today = %sysfunc(today(), date9.);

Answer (score -1):

For a SQL92 compliant database engine, the `where` syntax is as follows:

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM fielda) >= 13
```

Comment: won't that just return any items that are greater than 1pm regardless of the date part? I need it to be items from today at 1pm